# Windows driver kit for VS2019 and Windows 10 Enterprise 21H2

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019, wdk

What version of WDK do I need for VS2019 community and Windows 10 Enterprise 21H2?
I have tried many versions of WDK but for some reason the driver package templates do not show up in VS2019.
I uninstalled VS2019 and starting fresh with the idea that multiple versions of WDK  can be a problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the correct project template? I am using Visual studio 2019 and the WDK version that I am using right now is `v10.0.22000.1`. It works fine without any problem so far

Comment: Yes, I was able to get both installed using 19041.685

Comment: Oh wait, so its already solved?

Comment: Yes I resolved that. Now I am moving on to the real problem